# TypeScript inheritance type of functions

Tags: typescript

I've started learning TypeScript, and I have a question related to functions or to parameters. Is it necessary to use which type of parameter we have in class which extends other class like below? Or can we just use which type of function is move i.e. that is void and do not the same thing in the class which inheritance from that class?

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    constructor(_name: string) {
        this.name = _name;
    }

    move(dinstanceInMeters: number = 0): void {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${dinstanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(_name: string) {
        super(_name);
    }

    move(dinstanceInMeters: number = 5): void {
        console.log(`Slithering...`);
        super.move(dinstanceInMeters);
    }
}
```

Comment: "necessary" is not the right word. If you say that the parent constructor argument should be a string, it can be either `string`, either `any`. If you don't declare the type it should work since it will be marked as "any", though it doesn't really make much sense to have a child signature with a different signature compared to it's parent. Same goes with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll split my answer to *Can Do* and *Can't Do* as follows:

**Can Do**:

1. You can change your derived class (Snake) param type to `any`, with or without an initialized value, like so:

   `move(dinstanceInMeters: any = '5'): void {` or `move(dinstanceInMeters: any): void {`
2. You can change your derived class (Snake) return value to anything you would like, like so:
   `move(dinstanceInMeters: any = '5'): string {`

   (see `Snake` class in DEMO below can do's 1 and 2.)

**Can't DO**:

1. Can't change your derived class (Snake) param type to a different type but `any`, like so:
   `move(dinstanceInMeters: string = '5'): void {`

   Compile time error you'll get:

   > Property 'move' in type 'Snake' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Animal'.
   >   Type '(dinstanceInMeters?: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(dinstanceInMeters?: number) => void'.
   >   Types of parameters 'dinstanceInMeters' and 'dinstanceInMeters' are incompatible.
   >     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
   >   (method) Sname.move(dinstanceInMeters?: string): string

   (see `Dog` class in DEMO below.)
2. You can't Add another param to your derived class (Snake) move function, like so:
   `move(dinstanceInMeters: number = 5, anotherParam: any): void {`

   Compile time error you'll get:

   > Property 'move' in type 'Snake' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Animal'.
   >   Type '(dinstanceInMeters: number, anotherParam: any) => string' is not assignable to type '(dinstanceInMeters?: number) => void'.
   >   (method) Snake.move(dinstanceInMeters: number, anotherParam: any): string

   (see `Cat` class in DEMO below.)

Added a [StackBlitz DEMO project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-so-53768271) with your code to see it in action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for that you explained it to me.